# RealVNC connection ready at login page windows 11

Tags: windows-11, vnc, realvnc

RealVNC is already installed into my Windows 11 pro system.
RealVNC work perfectly when login into windows and all programs start (like RealVNC)

BUT

Like my Ubuntu OS I want to authorize connection VNC BEFORE login into OS.
In Ubuntu I installed RealVNC and nothing others thinks for working like as I want.

HOW authorize/launch RealVNC at login page Windows 11 and can connect remote without enter locally in my system.

"vncserver" service windows is already started and declared automatic

Specific problem :

Cannot access remote server with RealVNC client when remote server is on login windows screen.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.